# How can I change header when user is logged in django?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, vue.js

I have two headers header.html and headersuccess.html . I user is logged in, I need to change the header.html as headersuccess.html. How can I able to implement that?

My views.py is.. By this I am going to loginsuccess.html.. So, if login is success I need to change header from header.html to hadersuccess.html

```
def logsuccess(request):
    if('loggedIn' in request.session):
        id = request.session['uid'];
        return render(request,"loginsuccess.html",{'uid':id});
    else:
        return render(request,"failed.html",{});
```

I am getting uid using this. I am using html and vue js for displaying.

Comment: you can solve that in the template if you want like so: `{% if request.user.is_authenticated %} 
      {% include 'personal/loginHeader.html' %}
    {% else %}
      {% include 'personal/nonUserHeader.html' %}
    {% endif %}`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the view:

```
def logsuccess(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        id = request.user.id
        return render(request, "loginsuccess.html", {'uid': id})
    else:
        return render(request, "failed.html", {})
```

You'll probably also want to [read up on PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to follow Python coding conventions. Good luck!